# Get page number of multistep webform in tpl.php

Tags: webforms

I have a multistep webform that I would like to display a video only on page one.

I am trying to find a reliable variable that will only be available on the first page.

I have tried this in hook_form_alter but it is unreliable when the user navigates back to a previous page. It works initially. Page one video shows, page two no video, back to page one no video, page two video shows.

I am using drupal_add_js to add a display:none on the video div when page_number > 1, but it isn't working as I expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hacked it and used jquery to hide the div when there is an existence of a previous page class.